# Hide a button unless checkbox is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to hide the submit in a form button unless at least one of the checkboxes is selected. Here is a sample of my view

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input[type=checkbox]').click(function() {
    if ($("#radiobutton :checked") {
      $('#next-container').toggle();
    } else {
      $('#next-container').hide()
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" checked name="radio" id="radio">

<div id="nxtbutton">
  <div id="next-container">
    <button class="card__btn btn" id="nxtBtn" type="button">Next</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the length of the checked boxes inside a `change` event handler, if any are checked, show the button

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   var boxes = $(' input[type=checkbox]').on('change', function() {
    var flag = boxes.filter(':checked').length > 0;

    $('#next-container').toggle(flag);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" checked name="radio" id="radio">
<input type="checkbox" checked name="radio" id="radio">
<input type="checkbox" checked name="radio" id="radio">
<input type="checkbox" checked name="radio" id="radio">
<br />
<div id="nxtbutton">
  <div id="next-container">
    <button class="card__btn btn" id="nxtBtn" type="button">Next</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `.prop('checked')` on checkbox button to check whether it is checked. Loop thorugh each checkbox when one of checkbox has an onchange event and maintain a counter.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  
 $('#nxtBtn').hide();
 $(' input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function () {
   var count = 0;
               $(' input[type="checkbox"]').each(function(){
                 if($(this).prop('checked')) {
                   count++;
                   return;
                 }
                 
               })
               if(count > 0) {
                 $('#nxtBtn').show();
               }
   else {
      $('#nxtBtn').hide();
   }
         });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox"  name="radio" />
<input type="checkbox"  name="radio" />
<input type="checkbox"  name="radio" />


    <div id="nxtbutton">
             <div id="next-container">
             <button  class="card__btn btn" id="nxtBtn" type="button" >Next</button>
             </div>
             </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need the button to be hidden when the page loads.

`JS`

```
document.getElementById('nxtBtn').style.visibility = 'hidden';
```

`visibility=hidden`
is very useful, but it will still take up space on the page. You can also use `display=none`

Or, try the `CSS`:

`display:block` or `display:none`

Also, change `if($("#radiobutton :checked"){` to `if($("#radiobutton :checked")){`. You're missing a parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

I use this a lot on my sites.  Short and sweet, but all client side.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#nxtBtn').hide(); 
 $('#radio').mouseup(function () {
    $('#nxtBtn').toggle();
 });
});
```

```html
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<input type="checkbox" name="radio" id="radio">
<button class="card__btn btn" id="nxtBtn" type="button">Next</button>
```